# jQuery getScript will not load script

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using python scripts to generate HTML, CSS, and Javascript files. All files will have a filename based off of user input, so if you enter "filename" it will make filename.js, filename.css, and filename.html. Obviously, the HTML file now has to load these scripts based off of its own filename. I've got the CSS file loading perfectly, but the javascript file will not load. 
Here is my code:

```
$(function(){
    var url = window.location.pathname;
    // Gets raw filename, no extension
    var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1, url.indexOf('.'));

    var timelineFile = filename + ".js";
    timelineFile = "./" + timelineFile;
    var styleSheet = filename + ".css";
    styleSheet = "./" + styleSheet;

    // Load javascript
    $.getScript(timelineFile, function(script, text) {
        // Debugging
        alert( "Custom name javascript loaded.");
    })
        .fail(function() {
            alert("Script failed to load. Script name is " + timelineFile);
        });

    // Load css
    $('head').append( $('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />').attr('href', styleSheet) );
});
```

I really can't tell why getScript just doesn't want to work for this. The filename is correct, as indicated in the .fail() alert. This alert shows the filename to be "./filename.js"

Comment: http://www.javascriptkit.com/javatutors/loadjavascriptcss.shtml check this

Comment: Tried adding `.fail(function(jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {console.log(textStatus, errorThrown)})` to log error to `console` ?

Comment: That was helpful. Since the file is not http, it cannot be loaded. Looks like I have to find some hack to fix my problem now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the file was local (file\c\etc.), jQuery was unable to load it. jQuery has a set of files that can be loaded, such as HTTP.